# Update OPA data using PATCH

Tags: open-policy-agent

I was trying to update data in Open Policy Agent(OPA).
First I am adding the data using PUT http://localhost:8181/v1/data/user
Request :

```
{
    "admin": [
        {
            "action": "create",
            "object": "order"
        },
        {
            "action": "read",
            "object": "order"
        }
    ],
    "user": [
        {
            "action": "read",
            "object": "order"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add one more attribute to "admin" or "user" array. And one more scenario I want to update "user"[0].action value. How I can do that in OPA.

I tried PATCH http://localhost:8181/v1/data/user
Request to update  "admin"[0].action and "admin"[0].object:

```
{
    "admin": [
        {
            "action": "create1",
            "object": "order1"
        }
    ]
}
```

but its giving error "'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []types.PatchV1' Open Policy Agent"

Please let me know how I can achieve this update.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You need to update data using the PATCH verb as [documented here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#patch-a-document).

First, PUT the data:

```bash
curl -X "PUT" "http://localhost:8181/v1/data/user" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d $'{
  "admin": [
    {
      "action": "create",
      "object": "order"
    },
    {
      "action": "read",
      "object": "order"
    }
  ],
  "user": [
    {
      "action": "read",
      "object": "order"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Next, PATCH the `admin` list:

```
curl -X "PATCH" "http://localhost:8181/v1/data/user/admin" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
     -d $'[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "-",
    "value": {
      "action": "create1",
      "object": "order1"
    }
  }
]'
```

Finally, load the data to see that it's been updated:

```
curl "http://localhost:8181/v1/data"

{
  "result": {
    "user": {
      "admin": [
        {
          "action": "create",
          "object": "order"
        },
        {
          "action": "read",
          "object": "order"
        },
        {
          "action": "create1",
          "object": "order1"
        }
      ],
      "user": [
        {
          "action": "read",
          "object": "order"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You might be interested to learn more about the JSON patch syntax at [jsonpatch.com](https://jsonpatch.com)

Comment: This works for adding new array element. How to update particular element if we want to update multiple element and we don't know exactly the index value whether its admin[0] or admin[1] etc.... how we can do bulk update or add ?

Comment: How would the patch know which element to update if you didn't know the index?